# I am using odoo 8. when I install my module called Asterisk it will shows Error

Tags: odoo

Odoo Warning

Error

Unable to install module "asterisk_click2dial" because an external dependency is not met: No module named Asterisk

Ok

Answer (score 2):

This error appears when you declare `Asterisk` as an python external dependency in `__openerp__.py` but the python module is not installed or does not exist.

Please look for something like this in your `__openerp__.py`:

```
'external_dependencies': {
    'python': [
        'Asterisk',
    ],
},
```

Either remove this code if you don't need it, or install the Asterisk module in your server if you need it.

---

If you are actually talking about the OCA's `asterisk_click2dial` module that is available [here](https://github.com/OCA/connector-telephony/tree/10.0/asterisk_click2dial), then what you need is to install the `py-Asterisk` module on your server by running:

`pip install py-Asterisk`

Or if you already downloaded the code from Github:

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

Remember to use `sudo` if your user does not have sufficient access rights.